# Enable-ADAccount : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'

Tags: windows, powershell, command

Hey guys I'm trying to get rid of this error, I have a users.csv file that should create a new user, when I run the following powershell script. I am getting this error and am confused on how to fix it. Thanks for reading

1. The first piece of code is what happens when I hit run in powershell
2. second piece of code is the powershell script
3. is the usres file

Error :

```
Please enter the desired password for 'CN=Kevin,CN=Users,DC=ICS021,DC=local'
Password: Repeat Password: Enable-ADAccount : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running t
he command 
again.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\users.ps1:6 char:34
+     Enable-ADAccount  -Identity  $user.Identity
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Enable-ADAccount], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.EnableADAccount
```

Code :

```
$users  =  Import-CSV  "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\users.csv"
ForEach  ($user  in  $users) {
    $securepwd  =  ConvertTo-SecureString  -String  $user.'password' -AsPlainText  -Force
    New-ADUser  -Name  $user.Name  -GivenName  $user.'Given Name'  -Surname  $user.Surname -SamAccountName  $user.'SamAccountName'
    Set-ADAccountPassword  -Identity  $user.SamAccountName  -Reset  -NewPassword  $user.NewPassword 
    Enable-ADAccount  -identity  $user.identity
}
```

Csv :

```
Name,Given Name,Surname,SamAccountName,UserPrincipalName,Password
Kevin,Belanger,KB,2019,2019,password
```

Comment: You have no identity column in your CSV so therefore there is no identity property created when you import the CSV. Change $user.identity to $user.samaccountname.

Comment: your CSV file has a wrong header line. it says `Surname = KB` ... and i bet that aint correct. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I think a value for Name is missing or Name should just be removed. Userprincipalname is probably wrong too.

Comment: @AdminOfThings - yep, it looks like `Name` otta be the UserName or perhaps the DisplayName. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace

```
Enable-ADAccount  -identity  $user.identity
```

by

```
Enable-ADAccount  -identity  $user.SamAccountName
```